# Display saved User Content value(Html5) onclick into div element jquery

Tags: jquery, html, save, user-data

Hi i got a question how can i display a saved user content value onclick into another div this are my user edit save scripts

```
<script>
function saveEdits() {

//get the editable element
var editElem = document.getElementById("edit");

//get the edited element content
var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;

//save the content to local storage
localStorage.userEdits = userVersion;

//write a confirmation to the user
document.getElementById("update").innerHTML="Änderungen gespeichert!";

}

function checkEdits() {

//find out if the user has previously saved edits
if(localStorage.userEdits!=null)
document.getElementById("edit").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits;
}

</script>
```

now i want the stored user value be displayed in a div with the id code1 onclick of a button somebody a fix idea?
Edit:

The Usercontent should be displayed in this div

```
<div id="code1" class="code">User Content Value</div>
```

after a click on this Button

```
<a href="#" id="codebtn1" class="button" style="display: block;"><span class="fa fa-code"></span> Quellcode anzeigen</a>
```

Comment: @Pawan Lakhara edited ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

```
<div id="pwdDescription">
 </div>
<a href="#" id="codebtn1" class="button" style="display: block;"><span class="fa fa-code"></span> Quellcode anzeigen</a>
```

SCRIPT

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#codebtn1').click(function (e) {

          document.getElementById("pwdDescription").innerHTML = "Value";
        });
 });
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/bk7Na/2/

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job (without jQuery):

```
function showEdits(){
    if(localStorage.userEdits!=null){
        var target = document.getElementById("code1");
        target.innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits;
    }

}

var button = document.getElementById("codebtn1");
button.addEventListener("click", showEdits);
```

Comment: sorry not working for me cant get the user content value perhaps an idea look at my script above pls

Comment: he loads the url from window above instead of displaying demo with user choosen content